# CIFS mount incorrect disk space

Tags: ubuntu, mount, samba, disk-usage, cifs

I defined a new samba mount in an ubuntu VM via `/etc/fstab`

```
//x.x.x.x/share  /share  cifs  credentials=/.smbcreds,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=3.0  0  0
```

With this I get the following output from `df -h`

```
filesystem       Size   Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted On
//x.x.x.x/share  5.0G   79M   5.0G   2%    /share
...
```

This is a ZFS share on the host and I am using samba to expose it here. I would expect to see about 12TB of free space, which is what I see if I run `df -u` on the samba host. Running `du -f --max-depth=1` in the ubuntu VM reports this:

```
2.2T   /share
...
```

Which is the correct usage for the mount.

Ultimately I am having issues where services are trying to write files to the mount that are larger than the total reported filesystem space and they fail since they do a check on available space before writing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  The problem was actually on the samba host (also a VM).  I was mounting multiple ZFS filesystems into a directory called `/share`.

```
/tank/downloads  ->  /share/downloads
/tank/photos     ->  /share/photos
/tank/scratch    ->  /share/scratch
```

I had a single samba config share for the `/share` directory.  Because that folder was actually part of the VM filesystem and the directories within it were the mount points it appeared to only have as much space as the samba root filesystem.

To fix this I reconfigured my ZFS filesystem structure to only have one mount into the samba VM and that directory will be what is shared.